# Установка Хакинтош

Tags: mac, macos

Пожалуйста, подскажите. Я установил MAC OS X LION на PC(HACKINTOSH), при помощи Darwin/x86 boot v5.0.132, теперь когда я включаю ноут, у меня появляется консоль этого загрузчика, где написано используйте клавиши вверх, вниз, для выбора volume, у меня всего лишь один диск, он выбран по автомату, дальше написано, нажимайте Enter, я жму уже дофига раз, а не помогает, сиситема не грузится

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, такое случается, особенно если у вас АМД

В любом случае, серьезно работать с помощью хакинтоша не получится, а на девочек произведет впечатление и `Ubuntu` с установленной темой "под макось"

Comment: Макось - это несколько переделанная BSD, с фейсом от NextStep!

Comment: и к чему ты это?ну и про несколько переделанную 4.2 - настолько же бзда, насколько юникс, к примеру

Comment: Это я к тому, что в основе любой Макоси есть бздя! Оттуда и плясать надо. А с NextStep мне пришлось поковыряться ещё в 1998-м.

Comment: ну вообще-то в основе mach, а от bsd там примерно то же, что у линупса от gnuно я так и не понял, к чему ты про это

Comment: Для тех, кто не очень в курсе: BSD - Это Берклиевская ветка Юникс, разработанная Биллом Джоем в конце 1970-х. System V - вторая ветка, возникшая чуть позже, разаботанная фирмой  AT&T в начале 1980-х. Лично мне в конце 1990-х довелось админить и то, и другое. Так что, разницу между ними я очень даже понимаю.

Comment: :)что еще интересного расскажешь *по теме*?

Comment: То, что Mach изначально разрабатывался как дополнение к ядру 4.2BSD.

Comment: ну я тоже могу это нагуглитьты так и не ответил, какое отношение это вся "ценная" информация имеет к сути вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Тут вот есть неплохой список совместимого железа: http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page